# JavaScript - setting arrays containing variables in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I'm getting an error through a piece of script when using variables in setting an array.  If I just replace the variables with number values they have (which I have verified) I don't get an error.

Is there anything wrong with setting an array like this?

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
            [leftAmount, 'Get', '#2697C9'],
            [middleAmount, 'Neutral', '#E7E7E7'],
            [rightAmount, 'Don\'t Get', '#EB5830']
        );
```

You can see the whole function if it's helpful

```
function generateChart(viewerObj){

        if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers){
            var leftAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;
        }
        else{
            window.leftAmount = 0;
        }
        if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers){
            var middleAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;
        }
        else{
            var middleAmount = 0;
        }
        if(viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers){
            var rightAmount = viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers;
        }
        else{
            var rightAmount = 0;
        }

        arrayOfData = new Array(
            [leftAmount, 'Get', '#2697C9'],
            [middleAmount, 'Neutral', '#E7E7E7'],
            [rightAmount, 'Don\'t Get', '#EB5830']
        );

        $('.divGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only potential issue I can see is that most of the time you have...

```
var variable_name
```

...in both the `if` and `else`, but one time you have this...

```
if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers){
    var leftAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;
}
else{
    window.leftAmount = 0;
}
```

...therefore when the `if` condition fails, the local `leftAmount` will be `undefined`, and will be shadowing the global `leftAmount`, which has the `0` value.

I'd guess that wherever you're using that Array, it doesn't like the `undefined` substitute for `0`.

---

Change `window.leftAmount` to `var leftAmount`, or better, move your variable declarations to the top of the function.

```
function generateChart(viewerObj){
    var leftAmount = 0, middleAmount = 0, rightAmount = 0;

    if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers)
        leftAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;

    if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers)
        middleAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;

    if(viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers)
        rightAmount = viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers;

    arrayOfData = new Array(
        [leftAmount, 'Get', '#2697C9'],
        [middleAmount, 'Neutral', '#E7E7E7'],
        [rightAmount, 'Don\'t Get', '#EB5830']
    );

    $('.divGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData }); 
}
```

---

Here I also set the default initialization at the top. If you prefer, you can move it back to the `else`, or you can use the conditional operator...

```
rightAmount = viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers ? viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers : 0;
```

Or since you're doing a basic truthy/falsey test, you could do this...

```
rightAmount = viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers || 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  I did just change that and forgot to change the one variable. I'm using jqBarGraph to creat a dynamic bar graph and the problem may be with it.  I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object 00 has no method 'toFixed' - but only when putting in the variables.  I'll try making some of your changes to see if it affects anything.

Comment: @ShaneLoveland: The `toFixed` method is a method on Numbers, so make sure all your values are passing actual numbers, and not strings or something else. For example, if `viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers` is a *boolean* or *string* or some other type, it won't work. Those properties sound like they may be holding *boolean* values.

Comment: Awesome - that was the problem!  The numbers were strings - that did it!

Answer (score 0):

The only oddity I can spot is your use of `window.leftAmount`. Why did you write that? If `viewerObj.getActiveUsers` is not truthy now, the local variable `leftAmount` will be `undefined`.

However, you can shorten your script a lot using the [`OR` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) instead of various if-clauses ([How it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100758/1048572)):

```
var arrayOfData = [
  [viewerObj.getActiveUsers || 0, 'Get', '#2697C9'],
  [viewerObj.getActiveUsers || 0, 'Neutral', '#E7E7E7'],
  [viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers || 0, 'Don\'t Get', '#EB5830']
];

$('.divGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });
```

Answer (score -1):

you're using `var` to restrict the scope of those variables to the if/else blocks and then trying to use the variables outside of that scope which causes them to be undefined.  I would recommend declaring the variables in the same scope you're trying to use them.

```
function generateChart(viewerObj){

        var leftAmount = 0, middleAmount = 0, rightAmount = 0; // declare variables in this scope.

        if(viewerObj.getActiveUsers){
           leftAmount = middleAmount = viewerObj.getActiveUsers;
        }

        if(viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers){
           rightAmount = viewerObj.dontGetActiveUsers;
        }

        arrayOfData = new Array(
            [leftAmount, 'Get', '#2697C9'],
            [middleAmount, 'Neutral', '#E7E7E7'],
            [rightAmount, 'Don\'t Get', '#EB5830']
        );

        $('.divGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData }); 
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Using `var` inside the `if/else` statement blocks still declares them in the function scope.

Comment: oh interesting, I thought it did. Thanks for clearing that up.