# Variable assignment with || in value

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Can someone help explain what this line does, and how?

```
var scrollTop = html.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0;
```

Comment: What about that line do you not understand?

Comment: Use the first non-null value in that order : html.scrollTop, body.scrollTop, 0.

Comment: what is mean || && || in that sentence? How to explain that in "if else " way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of the logic a bit like this...

```
if (html.scrollTop > 0) {
    scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    return;
}

if (body != undefined) {
    if (body.scrollTop > 0) {
         scrollTop = body.scrollTop;
         return;
    }

}

scrollTop = 0;
return;
```

It is setting the `scrollTop` variable using a list of priorities.

1. First, try to use `html.scrollTop` if it exists and is greater than zero.
2. If not, then make sure that `body` exists and use `body.scrollTop` if it is greater than zero.
3. If all else fails, just set it to `0`

Comment: is that strict (html.scrollTop > 0) or we can write (html.scrollTop)?? Thanks

Comment: In this case you could just write `if (html.scrollTop)`. I used the longer notation to be more explicit in the explanation. In JavaScript the `if`statement can be used to check for any truthy condition (not zero, not empty string, not null, etc.) But you need to be careful if you think `scrollTop` could be a negative number.