# Common coding pattern: ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Currently I'm using:

```
input = input ? input : 'splash';
```

which I know is too verbose.

What is the shorter way to do this?

Comment: Just a little correction: `input == input ? input : 'splash';`

Comment: `input || splash `, if no input it will return splash

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'logical OR assignment' and make it even shorter:

```
input = input || 'splash';
```

If the input is Truthy value then its will take it, otherwise its will take 'splash'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using the or operator:

```
var input = 'input';
var input2 = false;

var splash = 'splash'

input || splash // logs input
input2 || splash // logs splash
```

[Jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/sexufa/edit?js,console)

[Stackoverflow explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)