# How to make a successful Ajax request using Javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am working on a shopping cart application. The user will add items to their 'cart' which is being stored in local storage. When the user navigates to a different page from where they were adding the items to their cart, the page needs to be populated with the items that they added to their cart(local storage). I am using handlebars to build the templates for my pages, NodeJS/ExpressJS to create routes and populate pages for get/post requests, and Ajax to send requests to and from the client and server.

Currently when the user visits the view cart page I have it working the first time through but, immediately after I get a 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.'. This is also being accomplished in quite a hacky/bad way.

To begin, here is my code for the initial get of the view cart page:

```
viewCart: function(req, res){
  if(req.session.success){
    res.render('base', {title: 'View Cart', userNav: true, checkoutNav: true, viewCart: true, cartIcon: true, js:js});
  }else{
      res.render('base', {title: 'View Cart', userNav: true, viewCart: true, cartIcon: true, js:js});
    }
},
```

This is just rendering the page with no data from the local storage in it. 
Here is the html of the variable I am calling to, to populate with the data from local storage:

```
  <div id="viewCartTable"></div>
```

In my Javascript I have this function that is seeing when the id "viewCartTable" is there and executing an ajax request:

```
if(document.getElementById("viewCartTable")){
  var data = localStorage.getItem("Products");
  Ajax.sendRequest("/user/viewCart", function(res){
    responseArr = res.responseText.split('^^^');
    if(responseArr[0] === "error"){
      console.log("error");
      setTimeout(function(){('','#000',false)}, 1500);
    }else if(responseArr[0] === "Success"){
      console.log("Success");
      var tableCart = document.getElementById("viewCartTable");
      tableCart = tableCart.innerHTML = responseArr[1];
    }}, data);
}
```

This Ajax request is sent to the post for view carts page and I believe this may be where the issue is really unfolding. He is the post:

```
viewCartPost: function(req, res){
      var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
      console.log(data);
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      //console.log(keys);
      for(var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var productId = keys[i];
        Product.find({productId: productId}).select({productId : 1, addProductGroupName: 1, productName: 1, productPrice: 1, productDescription: 1, filePath: 1}).exec(function(err, cartProducts){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send("error");
        }else{
          res.send("Success^^^"+cartProducts);
        }
        });
        console.log(productId);
      }
    },
```

This is getting the information of local storage that was sent from the client side, and finding the products and their information that match the productId that is stored and sent in the local storage.

So this current set up works the first time through. The inital visit to the page prints the data of the products in local storage as well as sends the "Success" to the front-end. But immediately following the Cant set headers after they have been set is being given. I believe that this is because when I find the id of "viewCartTable" I am sending an Ajax request. So there must be a better way to trigger the ajax request and send the data to and from the server and back to the client.

Is there a better method to making this Ajax request to get the needed data? Load and onloads have all failed me in my attempts thus far. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Part 2**

Iterating through the data and printing it in table format. So on the server side I am taking the results of this function:

```
viewCartPost: function(req, res){
      var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
      console.log(data);
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      //console.log(keys);
      var promises = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var productId = keys[i];
        promises.push(Product.find({productId: productId}).select({productId : 1, addProductGroupName: 1, productName: 1, productPrice: 1, productDescription: 1, filePath: 1}).exec());
      }
      Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
          // you may have to reorganize results to be exactly what you want
          // to return to the client
          var cartTable = viewCartTable(results);
          res.send("Success^^^"+cartTable);
      }).catch(function(err){
          res.sendStatus(500);
      });
    },
```

and sending it to a function that is building a table of the results from this function:

```
function viewCartTable(results){
  console.log(results[0]);
}
```

Right now this function is just looking at the first result. Which is the entire data set of 1 specific product. Looks like so:

```
[ { _id: 583df3eead025434e61a2172,
    filePath: '/public/images/df54528a827f99586135956e45f045fe.jpg',
    addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',
    productName: 'Far Cry',
    productPrice: 78.34,
    productDescription: 'Its back again. I have never played this game but heard it is pretty good. Wanted to write an extra long description to see if someone really took the time to type such a longer sentence how exactly it would appear on things throughout the application.',
    productId: 'rJUg4uiGl' } ]
```

In all other instances of me building a table like this I have been able to call results[0].productId to get the specific productId of the results. Here, it is returning an undefined. All other attempts have also returned an undefined. Any idea how to easily iterate through each piece of this data set? I feel like I am being stupid about this in the idea that I cannot figure this out :(

Comment: Which database are you using?  That affects the code I would recommend for solving this issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am having some issues iterating through the data. I added a Part 2 to my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was actually able to figure this out. Because of the way the array of information was being created I needed to be getting the specific pieces of data with results[0][0].productId in order to get the productId of the first result in the array of arrays. Hope that terminology is correct there. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This server code is wrong:

```
viewCartPost: function(req, res){
      var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
      console.log(data);
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      //console.log(keys);
      for(var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var productId = keys[i];
        Product.find({productId: productId}).select({productId : 1, addProductGroupName: 1, productName: 1, productPrice: 1, productDescription: 1, filePath: 1}).exec(function(err, cartProducts){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send("error");
        }else{
          res.send("Success^^^"+cartProducts);
        }
        });
        console.log(productId);
      }
    },
```

You have `res.send("Success^^^"+cartProducts);` inside a `for` loop.  That means you're calling it multiple times.  That means you're trying to send more than one response for this request and that triggers the error you see.  This is faulty server code.  You  need to only send ONE response for any given request.

I would have to understand what the desired single response is before I could suggest what code would best solve this issue.  If you intend to execute multiple asynchronous operations such as this and you want to know when all of them are done, then you have to write code to keep track of them and be notified when they are all done and then send one and only one response.

This can be done manually with a counter and some code to increment and check the counter or it can be done in a more manage way by switching to use promises to keep track of your asynchronous operations and using `Promise.all()` to notify you when all the asynchronous operations are done.

When you have multiple keys in this function, what is the desired single response to send?

---

I don't know mongoose too well myself, but `.exec()` in a fairly recent version of mongoose returns a promise so we can use that to coordinate multiple async database operations like this:

```
viewCartPost: function(req, res){
      var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
      console.log(data);
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      //console.log(keys);
      var promises = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var productId = keys[i];
        promises.push(Product.find({productId: productId}).select({productId : 1, addProductGroupName: 1, productName: 1, productPrice: 1, productDescription: 1, filePath: 1}).exec());
      }
      Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
          // you may have to reorganize results to be exactly what you want 
          // to return to the client
          res.json(results);              
      }).catch(function(err){
          console.error("viewCartPost", err);
          res.sendStatus(500);       
      });
    },
```

Comment: Hmm ok. The idea is for the server side to loop through to find the different keys. Which is the productIds of items added to local storage. I then need it to take those multiple productIds and find the affiliated data to that specific product from mongodb. Basically I need my response to be ALL of the products and their data in a table format. The data looks like this for a single product: {filePath: '/public/images/e6f5cab3de92a9365807cb8301f781b7.jpg', addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One', productName: 'Star Wars', productPrice: 3000, productDescription: 'description', productId: 'BJ_7VOiGg' }

Comment: @Zgbrell - I added one idea for a solution using mongoose promises to track your multiple operations, collect all the results and know when they are all done.

Comment: This appears to be working **Perfectly**. I am really really unfamiliar with the mongoose Promises but, it appears that it has definitely done the trick. It is sending all of the data that is needed to populate the table of products.