# How to properly use a for loop inside of a while loop in nodejs

Tags: ajax, node.js, loops

I am working on a shopping cart application. A user adds their products to the cart which is using local storage to store that information. When the user visits the view cart page, the page needs to give a view of all of the products and the number of times the user has added that specific product to the cart. So what I am doing is sending the items in local storage to the back end using an ajax request. I then find the affiliated information and build a table with that data on the back end and send it to the front end via ajax.

Here is the controller that is receiving the data and building the table, to then send it back to the front end.

```
viewCartPost: function(req, res){
      var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      //console.log(keys);
      var promises = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var productId = keys[i];
        promises.push(Product.find({productId: productId}).select({productId : 1, addProductGroupName: 1, productName: 1, productPrice: 1, productDescription: 1, filePath: 1}).exec());
      }
      Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
          // you may have to reorganize results to be exactly what you want
          // to return to the client
          var cartTable = viewCartTable(results, data);
          res.send("Success^^^"+cartTable);
      }).catch(function(err){
          res.sendStatus(500);
      });
    },

function viewCartTable(results, data){
  for(var i in data){
    console.log(data[i].count);
    var count = data[i].count;
  }
  var len = results.length;
  var i = 0;
  var table = '<table class="table-striped table-bordered" id="tables">';
  table += '<thead>';
  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<th>Image</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Amount</th><th>Description</th><th>Update</th>';
  table += '</tr></thead><tbody>';

  while(i < len){
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td><img src='+results[i][0].filePath+' alt="An Image" class="thumbnail-img" /></td>';
    table += '<td id = "productName">'+results[i][0].productName+'</td>';
    table += '<td id = "'+results[i][0].productPrice+'">$'+results[i][0].productPrice+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+count+'</td>';
    table += '<td><button type="button" id="productDescription" class="btn btn-primary" name = "'+results[i][0].productId+'">Description</button></td>';
    table += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="updateCartBtn" name = "'+results[i][0].productId+'">Update</button></td>';
    table += '</tr>';
    i++;
  }
  table += '</tbody></table>';
  return table;
}
```

Everything works out extremely well. Accept for the for(var i in data){} loop. This is getting the values of a dictionary of objects that have been added to the local storage. the console.log(data) looks like so: `{ rJUg4uiGl: { productPrice: '78.34', count: 1 },
  BJ_7VOiGg: { productPrice: '3000', count: 3 } }`

the data[i].count is specifically getting the count from each item. I need this for loop to live inside of the while loop so that for each item I can get the count of it and print it out into the table. When the for loop lives outside of the while loop(how it currently is) I get the correct information. The only way I can get the table to show any of that data is to set it to a variable which then only prints the latest piece of data into the table. But when I take that for loop and put it inside of the while loop so it creates another td element with the count, the table simply breaks.

Any idea how a best way to get this count information printing out into this table? It seems like the for loop could live inside the while loop but the code/application is not happy at all when I do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to simplify this problem down. This is far too much explanation and code for something that's likely a simple problem. Reduce the code down so that the problem still exists, but all the irrelevant code is removed. You may even solve your own problem when you do that.

Comment: Inside the while loop, `results[i][0].productId` is the ID of the current product, right? That's the key in the dictionary for the cart entry for that product.

Comment: Well I have broken it down to its finest of detail. I can update my code to only showing the for loop and while loop of where exactly the issue is persisting if you feel that will help. I have always felt that more information is better than not enough. Also, this helped me answer my issue in no form at all.

Comment: @qxz Yes it is. BUT that is not coming from the key in the dictionary. That productId is coming from the mongodb when we retrieve the data in the viewCartPost function. In the viewCartTable function, data is actually where the key/value is. So if i console.log(data) this is what I see -> { rJUg4uiGl: { productPrice: '78.34', count: 1 },
  BJ_7VOiGg: { productPrice: '3000', count: 3 } }

Hope this makes sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your while loop, the current product ID is:

```
var pID = results[i][0].productId;
```

To get the count in `data` for a given product ID, use that as a key into the dictionary of cart entries:

```
var count = data[pID].count;
```

You don't need to loop over every entry each iteration of the while loop; you just want to the entry for the current product ID. Thus, a `for` loop isn't going to help you. Just index into the dictionary.

Update the while loop to look like so:

```
  while(i < len){
    var pId = results[i][0].productId;
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td><img src='+results[i][0].filePath+' alt="An Image" class="thumbnail-img" /></td>';
    table += '<td id = "productName">'+results[i][0].productName+'</td>';
    table += '<td id = "'+results[i][0].productPrice+'">$'+results[i][0].productPrice+'</td>';
    table += '<td>'+data[pId].count+'</td>';
    table += '<td><button type="button" id="productDescription" class="btn btn-primary" name = "'+pId+'">Description</button></td>';
    table += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="updateCartBtn" name = "'+pId+'">Update</button></td>';
    table += '</tr>';
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: You have been a God send today my friend. I had been attempting to do this same exact thing. My issue was that I was not doing it inside the while loop, and instead had been doing my testing at the very top of the function which apparently was causing issues? I had been doing this and printing it out above the while and for loop. I am going to update this answer to show what exactly I did with my code to get this to work. But this has done the trick yet again.

Comment: so many ++++++ to you! I certainly owe you a lunch or five for all the help you have given me today with dealing with this process. Cant thank you enough and hope in due time my questions will become less novice like.. :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your programming jouney

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a templating library like [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) for your *non*-AJAX rendering, you can precompile templates into JavaScript functions which accept a "locals" object at run time and can be included with your client-side JS. It does make your site payload bulkier but it's definitely worth it.

Example precompilation step with Grunt and grunt-contrib-pug:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pug: {
        mysite: {
            options: {
                client: true,
                data: {},
                processName: function (name) {
                    return name.replace(/^assets\//, '').replace(/.pug$/, '');
                }
            },
            files: [{
                src: 'assets/**/*.pug],
                dest: 'site/js/templates.js'
            }]
        },
    }
});
```

The output templates.js contains code which creates a template dictionary named `JST`, which you can include in your client payload and invoke:

```
JST['path/to/template']({cartItems: results, ...});
```