# How to sum two object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck how i sum two object like this:

```
obj1 = { 
  'over_due_data': 10,
  'text_data': 5
} 

obj2 = {
  'over_due_data': 20,
  'text_data': 5
}
```

I went this output

```
obj = {
  'over_due_data': 30,
  'text_data': 10
}
```

One more thing, don't use a `for` loop, merge and extend. Is it possible to sum two objects?

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over object properties and get their values

Comment: `Don't use a for loop, merge or extend.` Why not? It will be more dynamic.

Comment: user like `Number(val1) + Number(val2) + Number(val3)` this will be helpful

Comment: @lonut Seems that is a homework question, with this restrictions.

Comment: @MudassarZahid Why convert a number to a number?

Comment: in some case it work like string if you are uploading code somewhere old server or using old cdn or jQuery version, this was happened to me, that's why @George

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with  simply use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjToIjPto_TAhXDQ48KHY_qAy0QFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg&sig2=jS-ZdRfhDKtd4bmcqilxXA&bvm=bv.152174688,d.c2I) function

```js
obj1 = {
  'over_due_data': 10,
  'text_data': 5
}
obj2 = {
  'over_due_data': 20,
  'text_data': 5
}
var obj ={}
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(a){
  obj[a] = obj1[a] +obj2[a]

})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution, using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var obj1 = {'over_due_data':10,'text_data':5}, obj2 = {'over_due_data':20,'text_data':5},
    obj = Object.keys(obj1).reduce(function(s,a) {
      s[a] = obj1[a] + obj2[a];
      return s;
    }, {})
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this if you don't want to use `loop`

```js
    obj1 = { 
      'over_due_data': 10,
      'text_data': 5
    } 
    
    obj2 = {
      'over_due_data': 20,
      'text_data': 5
    }
    var obj = {};
    obj['over_due_data'] = obj1['over_due_data'] + obj2['over_due_data']
    obj['text_data'] = obj1['text_data'] + obj2['text_data']

    console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Pretty much the only way if they don't want to use a for loop or similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can code it dynamically :

```
var resultObject={};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(objectKey, index) {
    resultObject[objectKey]= obj1 [objectKey]+obj2[objectKey];

});
```

Comment: You should use `Object.keys(obj1).foreach()` instead of `map` because you're updating another object.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below snippet to sum the two objects even if any of them has additional properties.

This solution is based on [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

```
Object.keys({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    accumulator[currentValue] =
        (obj1[currentValue] || 0) + (obj2[currentValue] || 0);
    return accumulator;
}, {});
```

```js
var obj1 = {
  'over_due_data': 10,
  'text_data': 5,
  'some_add_prop': 80
};

var obj2 = {
  'over_due_data': 20,
  'text_data': 5,
  'add_prop': 100
};


const sumOfObjs = Object.keys({ ...obj1,
  ...obj2
}).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue] =
    (obj1[currentValue] || 0) + (obj2[currentValue] || 0);
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(sumOfObjs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already have a lot of goods answers but I make a version who also handle multi-levels objects:

```js
let sumAllKeys = (obj1, obj2) => Object.keys({...obj1, ...obj2}).reduce((acc, key) => {
  let key1 = obj1 && obj1[key] || 0;
  let key2 = obj2 && obj2[key] || 0;
  acc[key] = (typeof key1 == "object" || typeof key2 == "object")
    ? sumAllKeys(key1, key2)
    : (parseFloat(key1) || 0) + (parseFloat(key2) || 0);
  return acc;
}, {});


// Example: 

let a = {qwerty:1, azerty: {foo:2, bar:3}}
let b = {qwerty:5, azerty: {foo:4}, test:{yes:12, no:13}};
let c = {azerty: {bar:2}, test:{no:1}, another:{child:{subchild:3}}};

console.log("Sum of: ", {a,b,c});
console.log("Equal: ", [a, b, c].reduce(sumAllKeys, {}));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this might be helpful

```js
obj1 = {
  'over_due_data': 10,
  'text_data': 5
}
obj2 = {
  'over_due_data': 20,
  'text_data': 5
}
var obj ={}
Object.keys(obj1).map(function(a){
  obj[a] = obj1[a] +obj2[a]

})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: How is this different from prasad's answer?

Comment: You could have at least used different identifiers -_-