# How to add the values from one object to another assuming the keys are identical

Tags: javascript

I've got 2 arrayys and I want to add the values of each of the keys together

```
const baseStats =  { CHA: 2, CON: 1, DEX: 1, HP: 12, INT: 1, STR: 2, WIS: 1 };
const bonusStats = { CHA: 0, CON: 0, DEX: 0, HP: 2,  INT: 0, STR: 2, WIS: 1 };
```

Expected result =  { CHA: 2, CON: 1, DEX: 1, HP: 14, INT: 1, STR: 4, WIS: 2 };

Comment: These are not arrays but objects.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Loop through one of the object `for let key in obj...` and  add their values to each other. This is one the simplest way to get what you want.

Comment: Looks like [this is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249813/how-to-sum-two-object-values-in-javascript/43249890) Bill :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to do this?

```
var result = {};

for(var key in baseStats){
    result[key] = baseStats[key] + bonusStats[key];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should use `const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @webprogrammer 's answer, assume the two objects you have has distinct keys:

```
let result = {};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(baseStats)) {
   result[key] = bonusStats[key] + value
}
```

You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if you want to know more about `entries`.

Comment: You should use `const` instead of `let`.

Comment: @KamilAugustyniak I agree that in most cases it's beneficial to define object as const. However, in terms of achieving the result that the OP wants, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, I use `Object.keys` and `forEach`

```
const result = {};
Object.keys(baseStats).forEach(key => result[key] = baseStats[key] + bonusStats[key]);
```

I've edited it based on the comment.

Comment: You should use `.forEach` instead of `.map()` if all you're going to use it for is iteration and causing side-effects. `.map()` is used when you want to convert each element in the array to something else (ie: map each element to something else). So `.map()` returns the changed array. You're not using the returned value of `.map()` here, so `.forEach()` would be better here ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree. My mistake, I've edited the answer.