# How to sum two similar Objects in Javascript / vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I have an object and I need to sum every `value` independently with another similar object like in this example :

```
CharacterStats: { a: 0, b: 2, c: 0, d: 0 }
ItemStats: { a: 0, b: -1, c: 4, d: 0 }
```

The Result should be

```
CharacterStats: { a: 0, b: 1, c: 4, d: 0 }
```

I found this answer [How to sum two object values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249813/how-to-sum-two-object-values-in-javascript) But I'm using vueJS so my function looks something like this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      CharacterStats: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    calculStatsItems(ItemsStats)  {
      var obj = {};
      Object.keys(this.CharacterStats ).forEach(function(a){
        obj[a] = this.CharacterStats.stat[a] +ItemsStats[a]
      })
      console.log(obj);
    }
  },
}
```

But i keep getting an error telling me "this is undifined" on this line:

```
Object.keys(this.CharacterStats ).forEach(function(a)
```

Is there another way to do it or fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.forEach` function, `this` doesn't refer to the `vue` component instance, so `CharacterStats` becomes `undefined`. Try this:

```js
const CharacterStats = { a: 0, b: 2, c: 0, d: 0 };
const ItemStats = { a: 0, b: -1, c: 4, d: 0 };

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    CharacterStats: { a: 0, b: 2, c: 0, d: 0 }
  }),
  created() {
    this.calculStatsItems({ a: 0, b: -1, c: 4, d: 0 });
  },
  methods: {
    calculStatsItems(ItemsStats) {
      const obj = {};
      Object.keys(this.CharacterStats).forEach(a => {
        obj[a] = this.CharacterStats[a] + (ItemsStats[a] || 0)
      });
      console.log(obj);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I only took the method itself and it worked like a charm ! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! ``arrow-functions`` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of both objects, and then make the operation, doing something like:

```
sum(values) {
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

calculStatsItems(arr1, arr2) {
  const prepareData = [...Object.values(arr1), ...Object.values(arr2)];
  return this.sum(prepareData);
}
```