# Create JSON object accoring to request.body

Tags: javascript, json, object, express

Using `NodeJs` + `Express` to create a REST API. Everything works well, but I can't understand how to iterate through the `request.body` and check its fields for `undefined` and `empty` values and assign new object only with valid data.

**request.body** looks like:

```
{ 
  key: 'value',  
  otherKey: 'otherValue',
  oneMoreKey: '',
  oneMoreKey2: undefined,
  oneMoreKey3: null
}
```

At that end my object shoud look like:

```
let contactData = Object.assign({},{
        'key': 'value',
        'otherKey': 'otherValue'
    })
```

Looking for your advices and help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Why not use a [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) like everyone else, and send valid values ?

Comment: @adeneo I didn't understand how. Using `app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {
    extended: false
} ) );
app.use( bodyParser.json() );` settings for `bodyParser`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JavaScript

```
function getCleanObject(oldObject) {
    var newObject = {};
    for (var property in oldObject) {
        var value = oldObject[property];
        if (value) newObject[property] = value;
    }
}
```

### Explanation

You can start off by creating a new clean `Object`

```
var newObject = {}; // same as new Object();
```

Then iterate through all of the object's properties using a `for loop`.

```
for (var property in oldObject)
```

Then get the value of that property

```
var value = oldObject[property];
```

If the value is `Troothy` add the property to the new `Object`

```
 if (value) newObject[property] = value;
```

Note that this way the `false` value will be rejected. To allow it to be copied to the new `Object` you should replace the `if` statement with

```
if(value || value === false)
```

Moreover, if the `Object` you are copying also `inherits` from some other `Object` it is possible that it will have extra properties as well and if you do not want them to be included you should change the `if` statement to

```
if(value && oldObject.hasOwnProperty(value))
```

**And Remember `for(var item in object)` != `for(var item of list)`**

`in` is used to iterate through an object's properties whereas `of` is used to iterate through an `iteratable` (i.e. list). Also `in` is supported in all browsers whereas `of` is not supported by `internet explorer`.

Comment: @vladja Also this will not copy any `false` `boolean` values, if you want `false` `values` to be passed to the new `Object` then change the `if` statement to `if(value || value === false) `

Comment: Be careful with `for...in...` loops. This will iterate over all of the object's direct properties and inherited properties from the prototype chain, adding a lot of overhead. You should use `.hasOwnProperty` to ensure you're only inspecting the properties attached to the object itself.

Comment: @Shaka This question was about simple Objects so I didn't that was relevant. Do you think I should update the answer?

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't hurt, I suppose. It's best practice.

Comment: @Shaka Okay I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
your_object = {
       key: request.body[key] || 'default',
       otherKey: request.body[otherKey] || 'default',
       oneMoreKey: request.body[oneMoreKey] || 'default'
       ...
}
```

explanation on how or (||) works [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: thanks, I know about Boolean logic, I didn't use it because I don't need default value at all

Comment: @vladja  You can follow nick's answer then.