# JavaScript operator precedence

Tags: javascript

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the === operator has higher precedence than the || operator, which is what I would expect.

However, this statement evaluates to the number 1, rather than false.

```
let x = 1 || 0 === 0; // x === 1;
```

You have to wrap in parentheses to get a boolean:

```
let x = (1 || 0) === 0; // x === false;
```

What is the explanation?

*Note*: This is not a duplicate of this question, which does not have anything about equality operators - *[JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)*

Comment: It evaluates left to right. The left side of the `||` evaluates to a truthy value so the right side of the `||` never gets evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: As Will said, this is a characteristic of how boolean OR (`||`) works and not an issue of operator precedence.

Comment: Along with generators, `||` and `&&` are seldom examples of lazy evaluation in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is like a parenthesis around the operands.

```
let x = 1 || (0 === 0);
```

The second part gets never evaluated, because of the truthy value of `1`
.

Answer (score 4):

`||` is a short circuit operator and conditions are evaluated from left to right.

So in `left || right`, if the `left` condition is `true`, the whole condition is evaluated to `true` and the `right` one is never evaluated.

In

```
let x = 1 || 0 === 0; // x === 1;
```

`x = 1` assigns `1` to `x` and the second condition after `||` is never evaluated as `if (1)` is `evaluated` to `true`.

And in

```
let x = (1 || 0) === 0; // x === false;
```

`(1 || 0)` is evaluated to `true` as `if (1)` is still `evaluated` to `true`.

And then `true === 0` is evaluated to `false`.

So `x` is valued to `false`.