# Check my cookie

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a cookie-value for somebody who visits my index-page with cookie.js like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script> 
  var index_da = Cookies.get('sw_home_visit');

    if (index_da < 1) {
        Cookies.set('sw_home_visit', '1', {
            expires: 365
        });
        console.log("nicht da")
    } else {
        console.log("da")
    }
</script>
```

As I get printed "da" all the time in my console this can have several reasons I guess; is this then right or what do I need to correct?

Comment: `console.log(index_da)`…? What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cookies.get('sw_home_visit');
```

This line returns `undefined` because the cookie does not exist. `undefined < 1` is always `false`.
Change your code in something like :

```
Cookies.get('sw_home_visit') || 0;
```

If the cookie does not exist, the value will be `0` and the cookie will be created. Or change your `if` condition to handle `undefined` results.

Comment: Thanks. I already it'd be something like that. So Cookies.get('sw_home_visit') || 0; sets the value of "Cookies" to 0? But is it then using the real "value" of the Cookie-variable at all?

Comment: @Daiaiai `Cookies.get('sw_home_visit') || 0` evaluates to `Cookies.get('sw_home_visit')` or, if it’s `undefined` or any other falsy value, to `0`. See [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100758/4642212).