# What is the meaning of ( $scope.something || 0) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am having some troubles to understand what this code do. Its a simple operation but i am confused with the result

```
$scope.diff = ($scope.diff || 0) - (e.model.ContainerReturnedNo || 0) + (e.values.ContainerReturnedNo || 0)
```

What is that `$scope.diff ||` means?
Giving numbers like `$scope.diff = undefined`, `e.model.ContainerReturnedNo = 3` and `e.values.ContainerReturnedNo = 4` the result is 4. Can any one explain to me please? This is AngularJS with kendo UI.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: Actually yes it is but i didn't find it before my post. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as everywhere else in javascript.

```
var test = something || 0;
```

If `something` is truthy, `test` will be `something`. If `something` is falsy, it will be `0`.

This is because in javascript, the `||` operator return the first thruthy operand.

See [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) for more.

Comment: i understand. Thanks for your quick answer Magus