# Is .concat() method used wrongly here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, promise

So, I have two ajax calls, which are chained in a promise.

For example

```
promiseData.then(res1, res2) {
 let responseOneParsed = JSON.parse(res1)
 let responseTwoParsed = JSON.parse(res2)
}
```

I am concatenating these two, like this

```
concatenatedArr = responseOneParsed.data.concat(responseTwoParse.data)
```

So, this is clear. 
But, sometimes one of these two ajax calls returns `undefined`, since the response is empty (should be), and I get the error:

```
  error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

Which is again very clear, but how can I scale this code to accept one of these parameters, if other is `undefined`, so it does not fail? Is `.concat()` used wrongly here?

Comment: How about a very basic check, like `if (responseOneParsed.data) ...`

Comment: I understand why this happens @JonathanLonowski, but need to check for that case..

Comment: It doesnt give error when the 2nd rsponse is undefined because it is passed as an argument to the function, its no calling the function. Its when we call a function using an undefined value that we get an error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Just make the API return `[]` when the result is empty so the code always works.

Comment: @ChrisG, I can't API is from third-party. If it is undefined, it is not returning array at all, but object.

Comment: A promise `then` will *never* pass two arguments to the callback, so `res2` is *always* undefined.

Comment: It passes Bergi.., since $.when() was used previously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily make it with `||` operator and `empty array: []`

like this 
`concatenatedArr = (responseOneParsed.data || []).concat(responseTwoParse.data || [])`

Comment: @stormec
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation

Comment: So this was a sanity checking.. nice. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just a case of proper sanity checking?

Check to see if responseOneParsed.data is valid, if it is, call concat, else, apply the second data.

```
 concatenatedArr = responseOneParsed.data ? 
   responseOneParsed.data.concat(responseTwoParse.data ? responseTwoParse.data: [] )
   :responseTwoParse.data
```

Comment: It is a two way street, responseTwo can also be undefined, not only responseOne