# I have been using following code but what does it mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, document, jscript

I have been using these lines in my projects but i do not know what does it exactly means, can anyone please tell me what does it mean exactly.

```
var myObject = window.myObject || {};

(function () { 

  //....my logic will go here

}).call(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myObject = window.myObject || {};
```

That declares `myObject` on the global scope. If it was existing before it takes the existing value, *or if it is not existing* it assigns it to a new empty object ([Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)). This is a common technique if multiple scripts assign properties of the same object, so that it doesn't matter which script got executed first they will always end up with the same result.

```
(function() { }).call(myObject)
```

Thats an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) were the context gets `myObject`, that allows you to write to the object easily with

```
this.someProp = someValue;
```

The IIFE also makes sure that your variables that you declared inside the function, e.g.:

```
var someValue = 1;
```

are *not* part of the global scope, so they are not polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = window.myObject || {}; // 1

(function () {                        //2

  //....my logic will go here

}).call(myObject);                    //3
```

1. Create a variable called `myObject` from an existing `myObject` property of the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) (DOM window) object or, if this does not exist, create a new empty object (`{}`).
2. Declare an immediately-invoked function expression ([IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)).
3. Call the IIFE by supplying the previously object `myObject` created (or retrieved from `window` if it was available there).

Notice that inside the IIFE you can access `myObject` as you wish. See in the below snippet how the printed object is the one created with a key `custom` and a value associated `value`.

```js
var myObject = window.myObject || {
  custom: 'value'
};

(function() {

  console.log(myObject);

}).call(myObject);
```