# Can anybody explain me this highlighted line of code?

Tags: javascript

```
 var roots = [], children = {};

    // find the top level nodes and hash the children based on parents
    for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = arry[i],
            p = item.Parent,
            target = !p ? roots : (children[p] || (children[p] = []));
         // I am not able to understand this line what it does
        // target = !p ? roots : (children[p] || (children[p] = []));
        target.push({ value: item });
    }
```

what I understand that if p is null then childrens for that parent should be empty but why then need to use of || expression that is used in this code

**(children[p] || (children[p] = [])**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `children[p]` is not defined (or this value is false, undefined, null, 0...), is setting with an new array.

> The Logical OR operator (||) returns the value of its second operand, if the first one is falsy, otherwise the value of the first operand is returned.

e.i.

```
"foo" || "bar"; // returns "foo"
false || "bar"; // returns "bar"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088161/3083093)

Answer (score 3):

## Step by step

- **`target = !p ? x : y`** means `if not p` then `target = x`. Else `target = y`
- **`(children[p] = [])`** means assign an empty array to `children[p]`
- **`(children[p] || (children[p] = []))`** means if `children[p]` is not null then return that. Else assign an empty array to `children[p]` then return it

## Combining it

- If `p is null or undefined` => **`target = roots`**
- Else

  - If `children[p] is NOT null` then **`target = children[p]`**
  - Else **`children[p] = []`** then **`target = children[p]`** which is an **empty array**

## Equivalent

```
if (!p) {
  target = roots;
} else if (children[p]) {
  target = children[p];
} else {
  children[p] = [];
  target = children[p];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**||** is the Logical **OR** operator or the **Conditional operator**.It returns the  first or second operand depending on whether the first is ***truthy*** or ***falsey***. A truthy value means anything other than **0**, **undefined**, **null**, "", or **false**.

This `root:(children[p] || (children[p] = [])` means that if `children[p]` is **truthy** then root is `children[p]` else root will be `children[p]=[]`. `children[p]` will be assigned an empty array rather than a **falsey** value

Answer (score 1):

It is a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with an inverted check of `p`, which is the parent.

If `p` not exists, then take `roots`, otherwise take children of the parent or assign an empty array to it, as default value, and take it.

```
target = !p                                // condition
    ? roots                                // true part
    : (children[p] || (children[p] = [])); // else part
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a more terse way to describe...

```
if (!children[p]) {
  children[p] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a ternary operator to check if `p` is not the item of parent then set the target to children and p elements array otherwise set to new empty array.