# What's the best practice for checking a variable in Javascript before iterating?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have a function like:

```js
    let statement = 'Some text with [square brackets] inside [several] times'
    let tags = []
    tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)

    if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
        for (let t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
            tags[t] = tags[t].toLowerCase()
            tags[t] = tags[t].replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_')
        }
    }

    console.log(tags)
```

As you can see I'm implementing this check: `tags && tags.length` to avoid an error being thrown in case the string didn't have any elements in the square brackets and if the `tags` is empty.

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Something is telling me it's not the best-case scenario to check the length of a variable to know whether it exists or not...

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the "elegance" of your current approach? It seems pretty standard to me. Does it work? Why do you feel the need to change it?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> let tags = []
> tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
> ```

This is pointless. You're creating an array and then immediately discarding it.

Just do:

```
let tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

---

Then, `match` will return either `null` or an array.

So you need to test for that. Since null isn't truthy and any array *is*, you can simply:

```
if (tags)
```

---

There is no need to test the length of the array at all.

If an array has a length of zero then the `for` loop you have will, itself be a suitable test. `t < tags.length;` will fail, and it will never enter the body of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check for neither actually. You explicitly define `tags` and if it's length is 0 the for loop will never run anyway. What I would do is make sure that `tags` was always defined in this way:

```js
let statement = 'Some text with [square brackets] inside [several] times';
let tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g) || [];

for (let t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
    tags[t] = tags[t].toLowerCase();
    tags[t] = tags[t].replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_');
}

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers so far are using a traditional imperative style but perhaps what you want is to move to functional style:

```
let statement = 'Some text with [square brackets] inside [several] times'
let tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
              ?.map(t => t.toLowerCase())
              .map(t => t.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_'))
              ?? []
console.log(tags)
```

The `?` operator makes sure `map` only runs when not `null` or `undefinied`. If nothing matches the `?` will return `undefinied`, short circuiting the `map` functions.

The `map` transforms the list into something else, so to lower case and then replace symbols with underscore.

The `??` transforms`undefinied` into something else. Note that `?` will return `undefinied` when nothing matches. When nothing matches I want an empty array instead of `undefinied`, just because it makes more sense.

---

You may wonder what's the point of using functional style. In this particular case it's more readable and less error prone.

Functional style is declarative. Instead of saying what the computer *must* do, you say what it *should* do. For example, you don't have to know how `map` is implemented, only that it transform a list into another list. It doesn't matter if it's implemented with a while loop, a for loop, or even if it's splitting the array and running each part in parallel; the result of `map` is always the same, given the same input. This gives opportunity for optimization in future engine updates (e.g., execute `map` in parallel) and results in shorter, less error prone code. In imperative style not only there's no opportunity for any optimization, but the developer may also have to know unimportant details, like how an array index starts (e.g., zero or one) or what state must be changed in each loop iteration (e.g., tags must be changed); the reader must pay more attention to detail and it's more error prone for the developer.

Comment: Wow what an amazing answer ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can at least safely omit the `tags.length > 0` condition as the `for` loop is a no-op in case of `tags.length === 0`: (initial `t` 0 and thus `< tags.length` even before first run of the loop).

For a purer version of your code, you could convert it to purely functional logic with `map` etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, the check `tags.length > 0` is unneeded. If you try to loop over an empty array the result is a simple no-op.

```js
let arr = []

console.log("before loop")
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log("inside loop")
}
console.log("after loop")
```

So, as long as you know you have *any* array you're safe.

The *only* thing you need to protect from here is `null` if the regex doesn't match:

```js
let statement = 'Some text without square brackets inside'
let tags = []
tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)

console.log(tags)
```

An `if` check is generally sufficient. I'd inverse it because I dislike nesting so you'd have something like this:

```js
if (!tags) {
  return
}
for (let t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
    tags[t] = tags[t].toLowerCase()
    tags[t] = tags[t].replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_')
}
```

However, if you prefer to avoid `if` checks entirely, you can set always set `tags` to an empty array if you get `null`. Then you know you can always handle it the same way. This is easy to achieve using [the OR operator (`||`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Also worth mentioning that `let tags = []` is irrelevant in the code - that value gets immediately overwritten. So you can declare and initialise immediately:

```js
function getTags(statement) {
  let tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g) || []

  for (let t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
    tags[t] = tags[t].toLowerCase()
    tags[t] = tags[t].replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_')
  }
  return tags
}


console.log(getTags('Some text with [square brackets] inside [several] times'))
console.log(getTags('Some text without square brackets inside'))
```

You can also use the newer [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which can do the same job:

```js
function getTags(statement) {
  let tags = statement.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g) ?? []

  for (let t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
    tags[t] = tags[t].toLowerCase()
    tags[t] = tags[t].replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '_')
  }
  return tags
}


console.log(getTags('Some text with [square brackets] inside [several] times'))
console.log(getTags('Some text without square brackets inside'))
```