# Short circuit evaluation and assigning either true or false to a variable

Tags: javascript, logic, operators, logical-operators

I have the following pre-configuration

```
const preloadedConfig = {
  "configA": null, // either true, false or null is allowed
};
```

and then I have the following initialization on page load

```
let finalConfig = preloadedConfig.configA || true;
```

The scenario:

1. Properties in the preloaded config can be changed to either **true**, **false** or **null** based on the user's preference
2. I wish to use short-circuit evaluation to determine the user choice on page load. If no choice(null) is supplied by the user, default the choice to true

My issue:

Based on the following extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088161):

> Falsy values are those who coerce to false when used in boolean context, and they are 0, null, undefined, an empty string, NaN and of course false.

The following is evaluated:

```
true >> evaluted true // ok
null >> evaluted true // ok
false >> evaluted true // the problem area
```

If the user supplies the config option of **false**, the final evaluated value will always result in true due to it being a "falsy value".

My **desired outcome** is a boolean value of **false** if the value supplied is false.

What should I do to make this work while using short-circuit evaluation and allowing 3 types of input values of **null, true or false**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead.

```
let finalConfig = preloadedConfig.configA ?? true;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `hasOwnProperty` check.

```
let finalConfig = preloadedConfig.hasOwnProperty('configA') ? preloadedConfig.configA : true;
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern environments (or with a transpiler), I'd use the nullish coalescing operator, which takes the right side only if the left side is null or undefined:

```
let finalConfig = preloadedConfig.configA ?? true;
```

Otherwise, use the conditional operator:

```
let finalConfig = preloadedConfig.configA == null ? true : preloadedConfig.configA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make defaulting rule a bit better by using old Object.assign or modern destruct ... prop.

This will override configA even with null

```
const yourConfig = {
    configA: true,
    ...preloadedConfig
}
```

With old env woudl be

```js
Obejct.assign({configA: true},preloadedConfig)
```

EDIT:

Taking nulls as default would be

```
const yourConfig = {
    configA: true,
    ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(preloadedConfig).filter(([key,val])=>val!==null))
}
```