# Please explain logic of the javascript function code line

Tags: javascript

can you explain how works **letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1**?

Answer (score 2):

This line adds letters from `pass` to the `letters` object as keys and it's number of occurs in the value.

So, for example, for `pass = "aabbc"` you'll have `letters` equal to

```js
{
  "a":2,
  "b":2,
  "c":1
}
```

The operator on the right (`(letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1`) can be splitted to two:
`letters[pass[i]] || 0` checks if `letters` has key of value `pass[i]`, if so the expression will have it's value, if not then we will get value after `||` - in this case `0`. To value of this expression we add always `1`.

Also, we could convert this one line to something like this:

```js
if(letters[pass[i]]) {
  letters[pass[i]]++;
} else {
  letters[pass[i]] = 1;
}
```

About the `||` operator in value assignment you can read more for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: thanks, nice explanation!

Comment: Hi Adrian, I already did that, but I am new at stack-ow, so I believe I don't have enough exp for the mark to be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the inside out, like JavaScript does. :-)

```
(letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1
```

That:

- Starts with `pass[i]` which gets the letter for index `i` from `pass` (which appears to be a string)
- Then tries to get the value for a property with that name from `letters` (`letters[pass[i]]`). It will either get a number that it's put there before or, if there is no property for that letter (yet), it'll get the value `undefined`.
- It uses that value (a number or undefined) with `(the value) || 0`. The `||` operator works fairly specially in JavaScript: It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is *truthy*, takes that value as its result; otherwise, it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. `undefined` is a falsy value, so `undefined || 0` is `0`. This is to handle the first time a letter is seen.
- It adds `1` to the result it got from `||`.

Basically, that's adding one to the value of the property for the letter on `letters`, allowing for never having seen that letter before via `||`.

Then it stores the result back to the property.